# Per VLAN QoS marking on HPE/Aruba ProCurve switches

Tags: hp-procurve, aruba

Is there a way to configure HPE/Aruba ProCurve platform switches to mark the traffic of the voice VLAN to DSCP EF(46) and Data VLAN to DSCP 0(best effort)?

I've applied the following configuration

```
vlan 1(voice)
qos dscp ef

vlan 2(data)
qos dscp 0
```

However as seen from a packet capture, the switch is ignoring the setting and the traffic from VLAN 2 is still not remarked with DSCP 0

Comment: You only want to mark the VoIP data packets to be `EF`. The VoIP control packets should be `AF31`. Typically, the phone will correctly mark the packets, so you should simply trust on that VLAN.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that an application in the data VLAN incorrectly marks the packets with DSCP 46 which fills up the voice queue of ISP routers. What I'm trying to do is to mark everything in data VLAN as DSCP 0 but no luck for now...

Comment: That is also why you do not want to mark everything in the VoIP VLAN to `EF`. Simply do not try to mark anything in the VoIP VLAN, just let the phone do it correctly. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to configure QoS on HP, so I cannot tell you how to mark the data VLAN to `BE`.

Comment: By the way, your markings mean nothing on the public Internet. Your ISP may honor some if you pay for that privilege, but as your traffic passes through other ISPs on the way to its destination, the markings are ignored.